# React Router v6 doesn't render / sync a specific route with the browser URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a few routes that I have configured this way:

```js
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />

    <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

The problem its that when I open `/`, go to `/about` and then go to `/contact`; the URL becomes `/about/contact` and not `/contact`, besides the page is not rendered. How to fix it, I'm using the [6.0.0-Alpha-3](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v6.0.0-alpha.3) release. I have read the documentation for this version and I know that the slash `/contact` indicates an absolute path and not a relative `contact`.

The links:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ListItemLink = (props) => {
    // React Router link
    return <ListItem button component={Link} {...props} />;
};

// Material UI components
<ListItemLink href="/about">
    <ListItemText primary="Home" />
</ListItemLink>

<ListItemLink href="/contact">
    <ListItemText primary="Home" />
</ListItemLink>
```

Comment: Can you show how you are handling the route changes? Like having `<Link />` components, using history API or whatever you have in your code once you change the URL from your code. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have update the question ( :

Answer (score 0):

You have to use to instead of href prop.

Here is the example https://github.com/smkamranqadri/react-router-v6-test

Comment: I have tested `to` but still the same result

Comment: Strange, try to use link component directly.